# Regex fails to match words with foreign symbols

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine

I have the following method which checks to see if a term used by a user is blacklisted.

```
  static checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, term) {
    return blacklistTerms.some(word =>
      (new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`, 'i')).test(term)
    );
  }
```

Strangely, it fails on words with special characters:

```
  it('should return true if sentence contains blacklisted term',
    inject([BlacklistService], () => {
      const blacklistTerms = [
        'scat',
        'spic',
        'forbanna',
        'olla',
        'satan',
        'götverenlerden',
        '你它马的',
        '幼児性愛者',
      ];
      expect(BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, 'scat')).toEqual(true);
      expect(BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, 'scat-website')).toEqual(true);
      expect(BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, 'spic')).toEqual(true);
      expect(BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, 'website-spic')).toEqual(true);
      expect(BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, 'forbanna')).toEqual(true);
      expect(BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, 'olla')).toEqual(true);
      expect(BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, 'satan-website')).toEqual(true);
      expect(BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, 'götverenlerden')).toEqual(true);
      expect(BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, '你它马的')).toEqual(true);
      expect(BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, '幼児性愛者')).toEqual(true);
    })
  );
```

All tests pass apart from these three:

```
      expect(BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, 'götverenlerden')).toEqual(true);
      expect(BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, '你它马的')).toEqual(true);
      expect(BlacklistService.checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, '幼児性愛者')).toEqual(true);
```

How can I fix my regex command so that it recognises these term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` matches a word boundary, but the first and last characters in the strings that are failing (except for the final `n` in `götverenlerden`) are not word characters, so the pattern doesn't match.

You can change it by matching either the beginning/end of the string, or some separator characters like spaces and punctuation:

```
static checkAgainstBlacklist(blacklistTerms, term) {
  return blacklistTerms.some(word =>
    (new RegExp(
      String.raw`(?:^|(?!\w)[\u0000-\u007f])${word}(?:$|(?!\w)[\u0000-\u007f])`,
      'im'
    )).test(term)
  );
}
```

You can see the character codes being used [here](http://www.asciitable.com/). Essentially, what `(?!\w)[\u0000-\u007f]` does is it matches any character from character code 0 to character code 255 which does *not* fall within the range of 0-9, or A-Z, or a-z, or `_`.

It'll produce a pattern like:

```
(?:^|(?!\w)[\u0000-\u007f])götverenlerden(?:$|(?!\w)[\u0000-\u007f])
```

https://regex101.com/r/AHRVgA/1

Another method would be to split the input string by separator characters (like punctuation, spaces, etc - like what's matched in the pattern above) then check to see if any of the words in the resulting string are included in the `blacklistTerms`.

That said, no matter the logic of your automatic filter, users are generally creative enough to figure out ways to get across the message while not triggering the filter.